# Подставить с помощью bash опцию для выполнения perl скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Есть скрипт на Perl, который запускается из командной строки следующим образом:

```
./script.pl "URL"
```

Мне требуется, чтобы вместо "URL" с помощью bash подставлялись значения из файла.

Как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: ./script.pl "URL" \`cat q.txt\`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и однострочником:

```
while read line; do ./script.pl $line; done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    path/to/script.pl $line
done < "/path/to/your/file"
```

Пишете такой script.sh и запускаете его.

Answer (score 0):

если в файле по одному *url* на строку, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
$ cat file | xargs -I'{}' ./script.pl "{}"
```

Comment: Никогда не понимал, зачем писать `cat file | cmd`, когда можно просто `cmd < file`. И манипуляции с `{}` в данном случае излишни.